# Reusing variable passed to function PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, reference

I'm fairly sure this hasn't been asked before, but it may be that I'm just phrasing it wrong when searching.

I'm trying to use the same variable as the result of a function as was passed into it as a parameter. I'm using the CodeIgniter framework.

The function in question, in the user_library class:

```
public function getLanguage($user) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $user = $CI->User_model->getLanguage($user);
    return $user;
}
```

Called from:

```
$user = $this->user_library->getLanguage($user);
```

NetBeans complains about redefining an already used variable, but I'm not sure how to fix this. The `$user` variable is an array passed between a lot of functions containing basic information, such as username, language etc.

It's for an eCommerce site, more of a learning project at the moment though.

I've heard of passing by reference, which is, as I understand, how the `$CI` variable is used, but am not certain if this is suitable for the application.

Many thanks to anyone who can help with this!

Comment: solution: ignore netbeans

Comment: simply `return $CI->User_model->getLanguage($user);` without first assign it to the $user

Comment: The code you posted is correct but if the type of the value returned by the function and stored in variable `$user` is different than the type of the value stored in `$user` before the function call it may confuse the IDEs that attempt tot provide autocomplete and other useful hints and checks. You can try to use different names for the variables. Inside a function or method there is no harm if you create additional variables; they are local and they vanish when the function/method returns.

Comment: In addition to the great suggestions already made, I would also encourage you, if you have not already, to spend some time coding in a texteditor that only does syntax highlighting, no code analysis or auto-completion. This will give you a better feel for what matters and what doesn't, so you can discern the value and importance of future IDE-provided advisories like this, which is actually bollocks. There's nothing wrong with reusing a variable per se, except for the potential problems outlined here -- all potential problems with you as the developer, not language errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help, makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often considered bad style to re-use function arguments as variables in your function - as functions get larger, it can get difficult to spot where things are being overwritten, leading to unexpected behavior.

IDEs tend to have modules which will remind you when you violate code style guidelines.

You can either:

- return directly without temporarily assigning to `$user`
- save to a different variable name
- re-configure netbeans to disable this type of code inspection

Personally, I'd recommend the first option.